# Is there any syntax in F# which allows me to repeat the command lines I've already wrote？

Tags: syntax, f#, repeat

say I have a parameter x and have several lines using x to calculate y, now there are 10 values of x and I need to use each value to calculate a respective y, and I don't wanna change x each time and run my command lines 10 times, is there any syntax in F# which allows me to repeat those command lines I've already wrote so that I only need to execute one time to work out all 10 values of y?

Thanks in advance

EDITED:I pasted my code down below, basically, what I want is geting alphas for different parameter combinations, my parameters are "shreshold", "WeeksBfReport" and "DaysBfExecution". I have 30 sets of parameter combinations, so I don't wanna go change the parameters and run the command for 30 times. Is there any way for not doing this?

```
let shreshold= 2.0
let ReportDate = "2008/12/15"
let ExeDate = "2009/01/05"
let WeeksBfReport = 1
let DaysBfExecution = 3
let Rf=0.01

let DateIn=ReportDate.ToDateTimeExact("yyyy/MM/dd").AddWeeks(-WeeksBfReport)
let DateOut=ExeDate.ToDateTimeExact("yyyy/MM/dd").AddWorkDays(-DaysBfExecution)
let DateInString=DateIn.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
let DateOutString=DateOut.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

let mutable FundMV=0.
let FundTicker=csvTable.AsEnumerable().Select(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>("Ticker")).ToArray()
for i in 0..csvTable.Rows.Count-1 do
    let FundUnitPrice= float(csvTable.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = FundTicker.[i]).First().Field<string>(DateInString))
    let FundShares= float(csvTable1.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = FundTicker.[i]).First().Field<string>(DateInString))
    FundMV<-FundMV + FundUnitPrice*FundShares
    printfn "%e" FundMV
//use TMV to calculate weights of CSI300 constitutes
let mutable csiTMV=0.
let CSITMV : float array = Array.zeroCreate 300
let DictionaryCSI = Dictionary<String,float>()
for i in 0..299 do
    let TMV=float(csvTable3.Rows.[i].Field<string>(DateInString))
    csiTMV<-csiTMV + TMV
    CSITMV.[i] <- TMV
for i in 0..299 do
    let Weight=CSITMV.[i]/csiTMV
    DictionaryCSI.[csvTable3.Rows.[i].Field<string>("Stock")]<-Weight

let DictionaryOldOut = Dictionary<String,float>()
let array=csvTable2.AsEnumerable().Select(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>("Stock")).ToArray()
let OldOutTMV=ResizeArray<float>()
let DictionaryOldOutWeight = Dictionary<string,float>()
let OldOutWeight : float array = Array.zeroCreate (csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)
for i in 0..(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)-1 do
    let Weight=DictionaryCSI.Item(array.[i+(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)])
    DictionaryOldOutWeight.[csvTable2.Rows.[i+csvTable2.Rows.Count/2].Field<string>("Stock")]<-Weight
    OldOutWeight.[i]<- Weight
    DictionaryOldOut.[csvTable2.Rows.[i+csvTable2.Rows.Count/2].Field<string>("Stock")]<- Weight*FundMV //OldOut Moving Value
    OldOutTMV.Add(Weight)
let OldOutTMVarray=OldOutTMV.ToArray() //create an array of OldOut weights and then sum up
let SumOldOutTMV=Array.fold (+) 0. OldOutTMVarray 

let mutable NewInTMV=0.
let NewInWeight : float array = Array.zeroCreate (csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)
let DictionaryNewIn = Dictionary<string,float>()
let DictionaryNewInWeight = Dictionary<string,float>()
for i in 0..csvTable3.Rows.Count-300-1 do
    let TMV=float(csvTable3.Rows.[i+300].Field<string>(DateInString))
    NewInTMV<-NewInTMV + TMV
    let Weight=TMV/(csiTMV+NewInTMV-SumOldOutTMV)
    NewInWeight.[i]<-Weight
    DictionaryNewInWeight.[csvTable3.Rows.[i+300].Field<string>("Stock")]<-Weight
    let MovingValue=Weight*FundMV
    DictionaryNewIn.[csvTable3.Rows.[i+300].Field<string>("Stock")]<-MovingValue //NewIn Moving Value

let table2array=csvTable2.AsEnumerable().Select(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>("Stock")).ToArray()
let NewInturnoverArray : float array = Array.zeroCreate (csvTable2.Rows.Count/2) 
for i in 0..(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)-1 do  
    let lastday= float(csvTable2.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = table2array.[i]).First().Field<string>(DateInString)) 
    let turnover = csvTable2.Rows.[i].ItemArray.Skip(3)|>Seq.map(fun (x:obj)-> System.Double.Parse(x.ToString()))|>Seq.toArray
    let lastdayindex : (int) =
        if lastday= 0. then
            let lastdayfake=float(csvTable2.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = table2array.[i+2]).First().Field<string>(DateInString)) 
            let turnoverfake = csvTable2.Rows.[i+2].ItemArray.Skip(3)|>Seq.map(fun (x:obj)-> System.Double.Parse(x.ToString()))|>Seq.toArray
            Array.findIndex(fun elem -> elem=lastdayfake) turnoverfake
        else
            let lastdayfake=lastday
            let turnoverfake=turnover
            Array.findIndex(fun elem -> elem=lastdayfake) turnoverfake
    printfn "%A" lastdayindex
    let TurnoverNeed : float array = Array.zeroCreate 21
    for t in 0..20 do
        TurnoverNeed.[t] <- turnover.[lastdayindex - 20 + t]
    let zerotwo : float array = Array.zeroCreate TurnoverNeed.Length
    if TurnoverNeed=zerotwo then 
        let ave_daily_turnover = 0.
        NewInturnoverArray.[i] <- ave_daily_turnover
    else 
        let ave_daily_turnover  = Seq.average(TurnoverNeed|>Seq.filter(fun x-> x > 0.))
        NewInturnoverArray.[i] <- ave_daily_turnover

type totalinfo = {Name:String;Shock:float}
let NewIn=ResizeArray<totalinfo>()
for i in 0..(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)-1 do
    let MovingValue=DictionaryNewIn.Item(array.[i])
    let Shock=MovingValue/NewInturnoverArray.[i]
    let V= {Name=string(array.[i]); Shock=Shock}
    NewIn.Add(V)
let NewInShock=NewIn.ToArray()

let OldOutturnoverArray : float array = Array.zeroCreate (csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)
for i in 0..(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)-1 do   
    let turnover = csvTable2.Rows.[i+csvTable2.Rows.Count/2].ItemArray.Skip(3)|>Seq.map(fun (x:obj)-> System.Double.Parse(x.ToString()))
    let zero : float array = Array.zeroCreate (turnover|>Seq.toArray).Length
    if turnover|>Seq.toArray=zero then
        let ave_daily_turnover  = 0.
        OldOutturnoverArray.[i] <- ave_daily_turnover
    else
        let ave_daily_turnover  = Seq.average(turnover|>Seq.filter(fun x-> x > 0.))
        OldOutturnoverArray.[i] <- ave_daily_turnover

let OldOut=ResizeArray<totalinfo>()
for i in 0..(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)-1 do
    let MovingValue=DictionaryOldOut.Item(array.[i+csvTable2.Rows.Count/2])
    let Shock=MovingValue/OldOutturnoverArray.[i]
    let V= {Name=string(array.[i+csvTable2.Rows.Count/2]); Shock=Shock}
    OldOut.Add(V)
let OldOutShock=OldOut.ToArray()

let DoIn=NewInShock |> Array.filter (fun t -> t.Shock >= shreshold)
let DoOut=OldOutShock |> Array.filter (fun t -> t.Shock >= shreshold)

let DoInTicker= Array.map (fun e -> e.Name) DoIn
let DoOutTicker= Array.map (fun e -> e.Name) DoOut

let DoInWeight : float array = Array.zeroCreate DoInTicker.Length
for i in 0..DoInTicker.Length-1 do
    DoInWeight.[i] <- DictionaryNewInWeight.Item(DoInTicker.[i])

let TotalDoInWeight= Array.fold (+) 0.  DoInWeight
let DoInRatioX : float array = Array.zeroCreate DoInTicker.Length
for i in 0..(DoInTicker.Length)-1 do  
    DoInRatioX.[i] <- DoInWeight.[i]/TotalDoInWeight
let Beta=csvTable2.AsEnumerable().Select(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>("Beta")).ToArray()
//let NewInBeta : float array = Array.zeroCreate (csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)
let DictionaryNewInBeta = Dictionary<string,float>()
for i in 0..(csvTable2.Rows.Count/2)-1 do  
//    NewInBeta.[i] <- float(Beta.[i])
    DictionaryNewInBeta.[csvTable3.Rows.[i+300].Field<string>("Stock")]<-float(Beta.[i])
let DoInBeta : float array = Array.zeroCreate DoInTicker.Length
for i in 0..DoInTicker.Length-1 do
    DoInBeta.[i] <- DictionaryNewInBeta.Item(DoInTicker.[i])

let mutable PortfolioBeta=0.
for i in 0..(DoInTicker.Length)-1 do
    PortfolioBeta <- PortfolioBeta + DoInRatioX.[i] * DoInBeta.[i] 

let mutable PortfolioReturn= 0.
for i in 0..DoInTicker.Length-1 do
    let PriceIn= float(csvTable4.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = DoInTicker.[i]).First().Field<string>(DateInString))
    let PriceOut= float(csvTable4.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = DoInTicker.[i]).First().Field<string>(DateOutString))
    PortfolioReturn <- PortfolioReturn + (1./float(DoInTicker.Length))*(PriceOut - PriceIn)/PriceIn

let IndexIn= float(csvTable4.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = "000300.SH").First().Field<string>(DateInString))
let IndexOut= float(csvTable4.AsEnumerable().Where(fun (x:DataRow) -> x.Field<string>(0) = "000300.SH").First().Field<string>(DateOutString))
let MarketReturn= (IndexOut-IndexIn)/IndexIn
let Alpha= PortfolioReturn-Rf-PortfolioBeta*(MarketReturn-Rf)
```

Comment: Not quite getting what you're wanting the program to do here.  Could you give a scaled down example of the code you don't want to have to write?

Comment: Your code does not look scaled down enough in terms of getting help with just applying a function to a set of 30 values. **Just wrap the whole thing into a function** taking these three arguments (instead of hard-coded constants as they are now) and return what is supposed to return. Then use Tomas' answer to apply different arguments to your newly created function.

Comment: -1 That is a huge amount of code to expect people here to read through, and non-idiomatic code at that. Please see http://sscce.org/, with an emphasis on **short**. ;-]

Comment: Sorry for not scaling down my code, but I don't expect people to read through all of it. I just want to give an idea of what my parameters are and what I am returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like John said, put it all into a function accepting the changing values as parameters.  To can use records to allow you to store the parameter combinations in a list, like so.

```
type ReportParameters = {
    shreshold: float;
    ReportDate: string;
    ExeDate: string;
    WeeksBfReport: int;
    DaysBfExecution: int;
    Rf: float;
}

type Report = {
    NewInShock: totalinfo;
    IndexIn: float;
    // etc
}

let createReport (reportParams:ReportParameters) : Report = 
    let shreshold = reportParams.shreshold
    let ReportDate = reportParams.ReportDate
    let ExeDate = reportParams.ExeDate
    let WeeksBfReport = reportParams.WeeksBfReport
    let DaysBfExecution = reportParams.DaysBfExecution
    let Rf = reportParams.Rf

    // Your function code HERE
    // Remember to move all type definitions out of this scope.

    { // Report data to return.
        NewInShock = NewInShock;
        IndexIn = IndexIn;
        // etc
    }
```

Using the code is as simple as this:

```
let reportsToBeGenerated = [
    { shreshold = 2.0; ReportDate = "2008/12/15"; ExeDate = "2009/01/05"; WeeksBfReport = 1; DaysBfExecution = 3; Rf = 0.01 };
    { shreshold = 1.5; ReportDate = "2009/12/15"; ExeDate = "2010/01/05"; WeeksBfReport = 2; DaysBfExecution = 2; Rf = 0.01 };
]

let reports = reportsToBeGenerated |> List.map createReport
```

Comment: Thanks for being so patient looking my code and this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not entirely sure what you need (what are other constraints and the motivation), but if you have some interactive code that makes a single calculation, say:

```
let x = 10
let y = x * x
```

You can turn it into code that does the same calculation on multiple inputs using e.g. lists:

```
let xs = [1; 10; 100]
let ys = [ for x in xs -> x * x ]
```

But as mentioned earlier, it depends on what you actually want to achieve - if you can add a realistic example of what you're trying to do, that would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've added my codes and I hope it is clear now what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you want to do something like this

```
let run shreshold ReportDate ExeDate WeeksBfReport DaysBfExecution  Rf =
    //The entire rest of the code indented - you may want to return alpha etc
```

Then you can just plug in the parameter values

Comment: Do I have to contain all the parameters in the last line if I use this?